# Pass a variable between controllers - Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to pass 1 variable to another view controller and then another view controller.

```
var selectedPlace = Place {
    name = Daniel Webster Highway;
    country = United States;
    lat = 42.72073329999999;
    lon = -71.44301460000001;
}
```

[image]

When I select on a cell, I have access to a variable `selectedPlace`

I want to pass it on to my PlaceDetailVC and also MapVC.

For some reasons, I can't make that happen.

## PlacesVC

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! PlaceDetailVC
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.selectedPlace = (places?[indexPath.row])!
        destinationVC.selectedTrip = selectedTrip!
    }

}
```

## PlaceDetailVC

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toMap" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MapVC
        if let indexPath = placesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedPlace = selectedPlace
        }
    }
}
```

I also try

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MapVC
    if let indexPath = placesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.selectedPlace = selectedPlace
    }
}
```

---

## MapVC

`print(selectedPlace,"<<<<<<")`

---

## Result

I kept getting

[image]

Any hints on what I did wrong ?

Comment: Why are you even checking the selected index path when your segue is triggered by tapping a button in the navigation bar?

Comment: why are you checking for the indexPath in the `PlaceDetailVC -> MapVC ` segue? if the `Map` right bar button item calls the segue "toMap" then it will never enter this condition.

Comment: The Map on the top right bar is calling `toMap` segue. Correct !

Comment: Can you check that, do you set this selected place from anywhere inside of MapVC ?

Comment: Yes, I did `var selectedPlace : Place = Place()` also XCode will error out while build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to check indexPath if the segue "toMap" is called by the nav button

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "toMap" {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MapVC
    destinationVC.selectedPlace = selectedPlace

    /*
    if let indexPath = placesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.selectedPlace = selectedPlace
    }*/

  }
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)